# adjacentElementsProduct function in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, methods

I'm stuck on an algorithm for a function called adjacentElementsProduct that accepts an array as the argument. It's supposed to return the largest product of adjacent numbers in the array. For example, if the argument is [2,4,1,3,2,6] it would return 12 because of the pair of 2 and 6.

my code is

```
def adjacentElementsProduct(inputArray)
    idx1 = 0
    idx2 = 1 

    while idx2 < inputArray.length
        pair = [inputArray[idx1], inputArray[idx1 + 1]]
        next_pair = [inputArray[idx2], inputArray[idx2 + 1]]

        if next_pair.reduce(:+) > pair.reduce(:+)
            pair = next_pair

            idx1 += 1
            idx2 += 1
        else
            idx1 += 1
            idx2 += 1

        end

    end
    pair.reduce(:+)
end
```

I just can't figure out where my code is not working. I'm just looking for a push in the right direction because I know just being given the answer won't help me as much. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

The code makes no sense :).
You are using + instead of *
And in the loop you always assign pair = [inputArray[idx1], inputArray[idx1 + 1]].
So you always return the last pair or the previous. If the maximum product is at the beginning, you still keep advancing the pair variable until the end of the loop.

Besides, the solution is quite complicated.

```
def adjacentElementsProduct(inputArray)
  index = 0
  length = inputArray.length
  max = 0

  while index < length-1 do
    result = inputArray[index] * inputArray[index+1]
    max = result if result > max
    index += 1
  end
  max
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why I've never thought of just creating a variable of array's length instead of writing `inputArray.length` every single time. Your method is much simpler than using reduce to find the product each time.

Comment: This solution was working for all tests until it began testing with arrays with largest products that were still negative. So I made the code `max = inputArray[index] * inputArray[index + 1]`. So it the first product would be the first two elements of the array by default.

Comment: OK. This is better.

Comment: is `do` necessary after the `while` line? I didn't put it and it doesn't make a technical difference in this function. Is there a larger purpose for it later on besides when writing blocks?

Comment: Do is optional. You can use a “do” a new line, a “\” or a “;” to separe the condition from the code you will execute inside the loop.